# How to make the default value of a type as Nothing?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr, types

For example Dim aInt as Integer should have the value as nothing instead of 0.

Comment: in C# at least you can declare `int value` as `int? nullableValue` which allow you to assign null to it (and it defaults to null).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to do that is to use `Nullable<T>` - i.e. (in C#):

```
int? aInt; // defaults to null
```

Regular integers have no concept of `null`/`Nothing`.

Comment: Also be aware that you still can't do `If Not aInt Is Nothing` in this case; you have to do `If aInt.HasValue` instead.

Comment: @Dan - maybe not in VB; but in C# you can use `if(aInt!=null) {...}`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this in VB too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use a nullable type. In vb.net - [Nullable(Of Integer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) (or Short, Byte)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, use `int? / Nullable(of Integer)`. Be careful not to overuse, though. I am working on a project where almost all valuetypes are declared as nullable / ?, and it is an absolute mess.

Comment: I agree. At first when they came they sounded really sweet but now I tend to almost never use them. It's a mess with all the `.HasValue` and typecasting that is needed.

Comment: Overdrinking water too is dangerous you know? A feature exists, does not means that you have to use it everywhere. People are saying dynamic is bad not because it is bad, but people will use it badly. No offense meant though. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I agree with Yogesh. The fact that people use them badly doesn't mean they are bad. Use them only if you need to have a distinction between a value of 0 and a null value.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you need to use int? instead of int.  Integers are value types and they can't have a null value.

With int? you can check the HasValue property to tell you it is is something other than null.

```
int? i = null;

i.HasValue // false;
```

to get the value use:

```
i.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer cannot be "nothing".  You need to declare it as:

```
dim aInt as Nullable(of Integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are right, you'll want to use a Nullable type. I wanted to precise the syntax for VB/C# and which version supports it:

VB9+ (Visual Studio 2008):

```
Dim aNullableInt As Integer?
```

VB8+ (Visual Studio 2005):

```
Dim aNullableInt As Nullable(Of Integer)
```

Whereas in C# 2.0 (Visual Studio 2005) you could already write it in both ways:

```
int? aNullableInt;
Nullable<int> aNullableInt;
```